# MVC populate input fields with values from FormColletion after return to View

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, model

I need to populate input fields with the original value that is send to the controller as FormCollection.

Model:

```
    public int MyID { get; set; }
    public int NumberA { get; set; }
    public int NumberB { get; set; }
    public string AType { get; set; }
```

The Model in the View is `IEnumerable<MyModel>` as the View has a grid with a list of Model entries for example :

[image]

A button in the view shows a hidden Div (via jquery click event) that consist of a couple of input fields. I use the following format for the fields:

```
<input name="NumberA" class="text-box single-line " name="NumberA" type="text" value="" data-val-number="The field Value must be a number." data-val="true">
```

The Controller accepts both the formcollection and the Model as parameters.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult NewVoucher( FormCollection frm,string action, CarnetVoucher model )
```

After showing the Div the user inputs the required values and saves it. The save action (NewVoucher) contains the input values in both the 'frm' and the 'model' parameters.

**ISSUE**
If the validations pass and the data is saved, the View is shown with the grid updated and the Div hidden again. The load of the Model ALWAYS gets the info from the database in order to show the updated info irrespective of the validations pass or failure. This is to show the data captured by other users as well (always updated and the latest).

However, if the validation fails, I would like to return to the View with the Div shown and the input fields populated with the values the user entered.

Because the Model is a `IEnumerable<MyModel>` I do not know how to do it as the Model returned does not contain the entered value only the saved value from the database.

I tried storing the FormCollection in a ViewData object with the aim of getting jquery to populate the input fields but am struggling with the casting. I tried returning the Model but the types mismatch.

I am thinking of adding the input values with a zero id to the model and using jquery to remove and populate as required but that seems a log of work especially if there is a lot of input fields.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was a stupid question.

Answer : Lists goes into a partialview with action returning the input view.